# Turn off Auto Smart Quotes in Word VSTO

Tags: ms-word, vsto, quotes, apostrophe, word-addins

Word has a feature called "Auto Smart Quotes", which changes straight quotes and straight apostrophes into slanted quotes and slanted apostrophes.  How can I turn this feature off, using a VSTO Addin?

I tried :`Application.Selection.NoProofing = True`, but it did not work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: [NoProofing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844920.aspx) turns off the spelling and grammar checker for that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no idea, but when I launched Word, pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> in the IDE and searched for "quotes", it became apparent it was

```
Application.Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False
```

and/or possibly

```
Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False
```